# How to configure HttpClient via Unity container?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to register an instance of HttpClient object with the unity container so that it can be used throughout the app, but running into the error - "The type HttpMessageHandler does not have an accessible constructor."

Here is the code I use to register the HttpClient with Unity-

```
private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<HttpClient>(
            new InjectionProperty("BaseAddress", new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiUrl"]))); 

        return container;
    }
```

Comment: Apparently Unity tries to create the `HttpClient` using the `HttpClient(HttpMessageHandler)` or `HttpClient(HttpMessageHandler, Boolean)` constructor. `HttpMessageHandler` is an abstract class, so it can't create an instance of it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the factory method to register it instead:

```
container.RegisterType<HttpClient>(
    new InjectionFactory(x => 
        new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiUrl"]) }
    )
);
```

Comment: This worked great, minor mistake is that BaseAddress takes in Url instead of string

Answer (score 9):

By default Unity uses the constructor with the most parameters. That would be `HttpClient(HttpMessageHandler, Boolean)` in your case. You need to explicitly specify the parameterless default ctor.

```cs
container.RegisterType<HttpClient>(
    new InjectionProperty(...), 
    new InjectionConstructor());
```

Comment: Good to know, and it did work. How would we add DefaultRequestHeaders with this InjectionProperty/InjectionConstructor style of configuring? With InjectionFactory it was do-able.

Comment: @RubberDuckDuck You can add multiple `InjectionProoperties` if you want to. And you can add parameters to the `InjectionConstructor` as well. You have to add all parameters the constructor takes in the correct order. If you want the container to resolve some of those parameters you can add the parameters `Type` as some kind of wildcard.